# Is it possible to have SwaggerHub generate a client sdk models without the '@schema" annotation (java)?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, swaggerhub

I'm using swaggerHub with openapi 3.0.0.

The java client sdk generates its models with an @Schema annotation above each of the getters.

```
@Schema(example = "12.9843215", description = "")
  public String getLattitude() {
    return lattitude;
  }
```

Is it possible to tell SwaggerHub to not generate the @Schema annotation? If not, is it possible to do it with the swagger-codegen? And if so, how?

The reason I'm looking to do this is because I only intend on using the models that get generated and would like to be able to use the github integration in case any of them change without having to pull the generated branch and deleting the @Schema's from every model. The @Schema annotation is from an import that I won't be using (io.swagger.core.v3)